How to avoid inaccuracies in logarithms?
I will show you my problem with the help of this code:
from math import log
print(log(1000000, 10))

The result is:
5.999999999999999

I perfectly know that the problem occurs because computers use binary system and we use decimal.
I have already tried the Decimal library, but it didn't help me. This code:
from decimal import Decimal
print(log(Decimal("1000000"), Decimal("10")))

was giving me the same
5.999999999999999

How to fix this problem?
Edited: I forgot to mention that the base isn't necessarily 10!

Decimal("1000000").log10()?

more general: https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1387438

If you want better accuracy and performance use numpy. numpy.log10(1000000) returns 6.0.

@N1ngu I don't think this is a dupe of that. OP knows that this is happening because of floating point errors. They're looking for a way around them.

I closed the question by the way

import sympy
print(sympy.log(1000000,10))

Outputs 6.
But, to be honest, it's better to be aware of the limitations of computers to store floating-point numbers to finite accuracy and not try to circumvent it.

You should try log10 as the following one
from math import log10

result = log10(1000000)
if result.is_integer():
    result = int(result)

print(result)

